# ClassNotFoundException when loading Applet in Java Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, applet, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to deploy Java Web Application (Spring, Hibernate, Maven, Tomcat, WinXp) with a very simple applet, but when I open jsp page with this applet I see **ClassNotFountException** Error.

The structure of my project (deployed):

```
myApp     
|--META-INF
|--WEB-INF
   |--classses
      |--ru
         |--mydomain
            |--applet
               |--FileChooserApplet.class
   |--views
      |--main.jsp
      |--index.html
|--resources
```

**FileChooserApplet.class**:

```
package ru.mydomain.applet;

import java.applet.Applet;

public class FileChooserApplet extends Applet {

    @Override
    public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Weather is good!", 70, 70);
    }
}
```

**main.jsp:**

```
...
<body>
   <APPLET code="ru.mydomain.applet.FileChooserApplet.class"
           codebase="../classes" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
...
</body>
..
```

I tried to change **codebase** attribute to:

- "classes"
- "/classes"
- ""
- delete this attribute

But,
if i add the same code for applet to **index.html** and double-click on this file (URL in browser starts with `file:///C:/projects/myApp/target/myApp/...`) then applet works.

Comment: *"..with a very simple applet,"*  No such beast.  At least, not when it comes to deploying them, as you have begun to discover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the applet will not have access to class files in `WEB-INF/classes`. These classes can only be accessed by server side resources such as servlets (as opposed to downloadable/static  content).

You can jar all the class required for the applet to work and place the JAR file in the `views` folder. Your applet tag will look like

```
<APPLET code="ru.mydomain.applet.FileChooserApplet.class" 
        archive="mynewjar.jar"
        width=350 height=200>
</APPLET>
```

A single JAR file is a cleaner way to do deployments.

Comment: I made jar file with applet class, replaced it into `resources` folder, added attribute `archive="resources/myApplet.jar"` to `<applet>` tag and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, other answers had the `codebase` attribute instead of `archive` and that changed got it working for me.